# HTTP Response String to 2D Swift Array

Tags: swift

I am wandering if anyone has done anything similar to this. I make a `http` request and the response is a two dimensional array, for example,

```
[["Column1","Column2","Column3","Column4"],["1","2","3","4"]]
```

I am trying to convert the "text/array" in the `http` response to a 2D array in Swift. Has anyone done anything like this?

I understand that I can have the `http` response come back in the JSON format and the use of `JSONDecode`, but that is not what I want to do in this particular case.

Comment: Use `JSONSerialization` and cast the type to `[[String]]`. Pretty straightforward.

Comment: Awesome, that is exactly what i was looking for!!! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
let responseString =  "[[\"Column1\",\"Column2\",\"Column3\",\"Column4\"],[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\"]]"
let data = responseString.data(using: .utf8)!
if let output : [[String]] = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String]]{
    print(output)
}
```

output:

> [["Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4"], ["1", "2", "3", "4"]]

Comment: Awesome, that is exactly what i was looking for!!! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ItecaSolutions - accept the answer if works for you, it helps others too in choosing correct answer :)

Comment: @Rocky avoid force unwrapping

Comment: @ItecaSolutions [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/381994)